# Is Gitlab self hosted Enterprise Edition free?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ee

I have installed latest Gitlab EE on one of my servers hosted on my company's infrastructure.
Is it free to use all the way or at some point we need to pay for this?
I have read through the documentation on Gitlab site but not able to understand fully.

Let me know if someone can advice.

Comment: This might help: https://about.gitlab.com/install/ce-or-ee/ . From how I understand it, if you don't have an EE license you don't have access to paid features.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah I have gone through it. It seems I can use all the core features for free and for the premium features I have to buy the license.
Also do you know if there is any limitation number of users, repository we can create under free version?

Comment: The free version is 100 % open source and is not limited in anyway. You can also install the EE version and never add a license. Then you have a CE version with the possibility to add a licence later

Comment: Not about software, about pricing on a commercial product.